# How to use !.equals with strings?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, equals

We're working on a group assignment.  Part of the program is for the use to input "pay", followed by the student's SIN (social insurance number) and how much to deduct their account by.  For example, `pay,193678187,900`.

The SIN is compared to a list of SINs from a file, generated into an array and compared, `curSin.equals(stuSin))`.  `curSin` and `stuSin` are both Strings.

If the SIN is found, it will reduce the ammount from the student's balance (not shown) and write it to the file `write(student,inrec)`.

If the SIN isn't found, it should return "SIN not found".
Our problem is that even if the SIN is found, it still returns "SIN not found".  We think it has something to do with the if statement and the not equals comparison, but we've tried everything we can think of and can't get it to work properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Code snippet below.

```
    if (cmd.equals("pay") && p.length == 3)
    { // first word is "pay";three terms (cmd, sin, $)
        System.out.println("pay");
        // Pay: decreases student payment, notifies of overpayment
        String stuSin = p[1];
        double stupay = Double.parseDouble(p[2]);
        for (int i = 0; i < student.length; i++)
        {
            Student x1 = student[i];
            String curSin = x1.getSin();
            if (curSin.equals(stuSin))
            {
                double curpay = x1.getBal();
                double newBal = curpay - stupay;
                if (stupay > curpay)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Overpayment");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                x1.setBal(newBal);
                System.out.println(x1.getBal());

                write(student, inrec);
            }
            else if (!curSin.equals(stuSin))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SIN not found"); // sin not found
                System.exit(0);
            }

        }// end of for loop
    }
```

Comment: Debug! Put `System.out.println(cmd)` before `if`. Also `p.length==3` is superfluous.

Comment: why in your else statement your have an if condition ? you check the same condition in your first if ( if (curSin.equals(stuSin)) ).

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz I don't think p.length is superfluous.  Since this is just a code fragment, it is impossible to tell, but I would guess it is needed.

Comment: It helps A LOT if you indent your code correctly.  Some might quibble about `{` on a newline or on the previous line, but basic indentation (whichever variant you choose) is very important.  I reformatted the code to make it more readable.

Comment: @emory: Ah, I thought it is `cmd.length() == 3` - you are right, sorry.

Comment: We need p.equals for a part of the code that isn't shown.
Sorry about our indenting; we're new to Java.

Comment: You should use proper indenting in any language that allows it.  (Pretty much everything but RPG.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your use of the equals method.

You should add a couple debug statments (or actually use a debugger) to make sure that you're really comparing the strings you want.

```
System.out.println("stuSin: '" + stuSin + "'");
System.out.println("curSin: '" + curSin + "'");
```

Comment: Didn't think of that!  Fixed the problem, we just needed to exit the for loop after finding the SIN first time around.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your program would work correctly if the first in the list was a correct match.

But the first is not a correct match.  So it exits without ever looking at the second.

You probably want to iterate over all students and 
the first time it matches break out of the loop.

If and only if you iterate over all students without matching run the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"SIN not found"); //sin not found`

Comment: Looking at it again, we see this problem as well.  However, we have no idea how to fix it.